# How do you specify an integration request with API gateway and Kinesis data streams in terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I'm having trouble declaring an integration request resource in terraform that allows an API GateWay Method to push to a Kinesis data stream. I found [this](https://github.com/dod-iac/terraform-aws-kinesis-api-gateway/blob/master/main.tf) (See line 510) however I'm having a hard time understanding since it seems to specify which shard to post to and i thought this was done dynamically based on some id (eg. user_id). Any help?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "post_method_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.the_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.the_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri = format(
    "arn:%s:apigateway:%s:kinesis:action/PutRecord",
    data.aws_partition.current.partition,
    var.default_region
  )
}
```

Edit: I solved it with

```
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.default_region}:kinesis:action/PutRecord"
credentials = aws_iam_role.api_gw_kinesis_role.arn
```

Comment: Isn't the ARN the ARN of entire stream and not only a shard?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can your rephrase?

Comment: The URI you are trying to pass to the integration resource should be an ARN of the entire stream, not only ARN of a shard?

Comment: if i put `uri = aws_kinesis_stream.my_declared_stream.arn` then i get `Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action`

Comment: Have you maybe checked this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html?

Comment: i've been reading through it but it doesn't seem to clarify what i'm supposed to put in the uri